# Not Able to get Auth::user->id in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Here is my Controller.

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: ed
 * Date: 05/02/16
 * Time: 09:33
 */

namespace App\Http\Controllers\API\V1;

use App\Certificate;
use App\Country;
use App\Film;
use App\FilmExtra;
use App\FilmFavourite;
use App\FilmGenre;
use App\FilmLike;
use App\FilmView;
use App\Genre;
use App\Language;
use App\Magazine;
use App\News;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;

class MagazineController extends ApiController
{
    public function viewAll(){



        echo Auth::user()->id;
        exit;

        $user_id = Input::get('user_id');

        $magazines = Magazine::paginate(5);
        return parent::api_response($magazines->toArray(), true, ['return' => 'all magazines'], 200);
    }

    public function getMagazine($id){
        $magazine = Magazine::find($id);
        if($magazine){
            return parent::api_response($magazine->toArray(), true, ['return' => 'magazine details'], 200);
        }else{
            return parent::api_response([], false, ['error' => 'Couldn\'t find that magazine'], 404);
        }
    }

    protected function getURL($id){
        $magazine = Magazine::find($id);
        if($magazine){
            return parent::api_response(['url' => $magazine->file_url], true, ['return' => 'magazine url'], 200);
        }else{
            return parent::api_response([], false, ['error' => 'Couldn\'t find that magazine'], 404);
        }
    }

    public function search($term){
        $magazines = Magazine::search($term)->paginate(5);
        return parent::api_response($magazines, true, ['return' => 'search for '.$term], 200);
    }

    public function purchased(){

        $magazines = Magazine::leftJoin('ordered_items', 'ordered_items.item_id', '=', 'magazines.id')
                        ->leftJoin('orders', 'orders.id', '=', 'ordered_items.order_id')
                        ->leftJoin('items', 'items.id', '=', 'ordered_items.item_id')
                        ->where('orders.user_id', $user_id)
                        ->where('items.class', 'book');

        if(Input::get('filter')) {
            $jsonFilter = Input::get('filter');
            $filters = json_decode($jsonFilter);

            foreach ($filters as $filter => $value){
                switch ($filter){
                    case "genre":
                        if($value){
                            $magazines = $magazines->whereHas('genre', function ($query) use($value) {
                                $query->whereIn('genre_id', $value);
                            });
                        }
                        break;
                    case "cert":
                       if($value){
                           $magazines = $magazines->whereIn('cert', $value);
                       }
                        break;
                    case "country":
                        if($value){
                            $magazines = $magazines->whereIn('country', $value);
                        }
                        break;
                    case "lang":
                       if($value){
                           $magazines = $magazines->whereHas('languages', function ($query) use($value) {
                               $query->whereIn('language_id', $value);
                           });
                       }
                        break;
                }
            }


        }

        $magazines = $magazines->paginate(5);

        return parent::api_response($magazines->toArray(), true, ['return' => 'all magazines'], 200);
    }

}
```

If i call any of the function for this controller i am not able to get my `Auth::user()->id`.

it's throwing an error.

> ErrorException in MagazineController.php line 54:
>   **Trying to get property of non-object**

If i try to echo `Auth::user()->id` in any other controller, its working fine.

using `laravel 5.2`

Can anybody help me ?

don't hesitate to ask any question if you want.

Comment: What do you mean you're not able to get it? Is it throwing an error? Or just nothing is showing up?

Comment: @Samsquanch yeah throwing an error .ErrorException in MagazineController.php line 54:
Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: $user = Auth::user(); echo $user->id; exit;

Comment: @DevinGray , just tried it,   same error.  I wonder its not working on this controller only.

Comment: Try this: `if (Auth::check()) { echo "test"; exit; }` -- if you don't get 'test' then you're not authorized.

Comment: try to `dd(Auth::user());` and post the result.

Comment: Also are your facades referenced correctly?

Comment: @Samsquanch , i just said in other controllee its working fine,  user has Authenticated,

Comment: Even Auth::logout is also not working .. i tried a call to logout function. then i trued to echo Auth::user()->id, and it was returning me id .  How strange.

Comment: As I see is an API controller what Auth Guard are you using ?

Comment: @DevinGray , facades are correct m those are working find with the other controllers and Model.

Comment: @IsmailRBOUH

'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
    ],

Comment: Please try `Auth::guard('web')->user()->id` !

Comment: @IsmailRBOUH , same error . need somebody to add me on skype : punit.aavid    and resolve this issue

Comment: @PunitGajjar I'm not sure you understand what debugging is. It's stepping through the obvious steps to figure out what's going wrong and where it's going wrong. Saying "it works in the other controllers" isn't helping you or anyone else trying to help you.

Comment: @Samsquanch, Can you add me over skype and help me ? 

my skype is : punit.aavid

Comment: Of course try the other guard `Auth::guard('api')->user()->id`. That's really strange if the user is already Authenticated.

Comment: @IsmailRBOUH, Can you please come over skype ?

Comment: I'm really sorry VoIP via ADSL is blocked in my country :S !

Comment: Can you try using `use Auth;` instead of `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;` ?

Comment: If the error says line 54, I think the problem isn't `Auth`, since `Auth::user()->id` is on the line 34. Probably it was `api_response` method of your `ApiController` that trigger the error?

Comment: @PunitGajjar @Rifki is right here, yon need to rewrite your check like so: `if(!is_null($magazine))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the `Auth::user` returns `null`and you are trying to get `id` of null.

So make sure that user is logged like:

```
if (Auth::check()) {
  // The user is logged in...
  echo Auth::user()->id;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What ApiController do?

Change the namespace at the top to

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
```

Try to change `ApiController` with plain `Controller` and check what will be happen

Instead of:

```
class MagazineController extends ApiController
```

Change it like so:

```
class MagazineController extends Controller
```

Comment: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\API\V1\Controller' not found

Comment: Its done. Buddy Thank you all for your quick response.

Comment: It's my pleasure bro. If my answer helped you choose it as accepted answer

Comment: Problem was something else but  My code structure is like that only.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure your routes for this controller are wrapped in the `web` middleware group.

Also, since `MagazineController` extends `ApiController`, ensure that `ApiController` extends `Controller`.

Comment: Its like that only. still  i dnt know why its not working

Answer (score 0):

**Use it like this the Laravel 5.2 way**

```
$user_collection = Auth::user();
echo $user_collection->id;
exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you changed the id name of your users table? I experienced that. I made mine all capital (ID). I was on Linux and db, table, and column names are case sensitive. Try checking the id column of your users table.

That is, if you're sure that the user is logged in. Else, it would be null if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Can you please come over to skype and help me . ?  I have checked all the things. everything seems correct

Answer (score 0):

Put your controller under a login Middleware to ensure you have a logged in user, or simply put a verification before you access user id:

```php
if (Auth::check()) {
    $id = Auth::user()->id;
}
```